# Should edit suggestions be used only when the post to be edited has multiple issues?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

[This edit suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7487) of mine was rejected some minutes ago.

Questions:

- Is there something else that could have been improved in that post? I really could not see any such things. The post is grammatically perfect to my eye, excluding the tiny typo.
- If not, does this mean I should refrain from suggesting edits to posts that only have small typos requiring less than 6 character modifications?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The edit you would have done is too minor, as you were just changing due characters to fix the spelling of *question*. The other edit was not necessary, except (probably) for allowing you to suggest an edit.

That possibly sounded, to who reviewed the edit, as a way to circumnavigate the limit of 6 characters. The reason there is the limit is that the suggested edit is going to be reviewed, and it should be worth the time spent from who reviews it.

In general, I would suggest to avoid small edits, when they are reviewed from other users. There are some cases where the suggested edit would be acceptable, though. Suppose that you saw a post with a link that takes to a 404 error page, and you find the correct link; in that case, the suggested edit could be accepted, even if you had to change a word that didn't need to be changed, especially if you note in the comment that the change was to fix the wrong link.

Comment: Maybe it would be best to send a warning to the users asking for more major edits, but at the same time, approve it "for now"? It helped a little, so why waste it, similarly to the ideology at [Ask Ubuntu](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/3944/54298)?

Comment: When users suggest an edit that doesn't change 6 or more characters, they get an error message. At the top of the edit page they read, "We welcome all constructive edits, but please make them substantial. Avoid trivial, tiny one-letter edits unless absolutely necessary." It should be clear what kind of edits they are supposed to do.

Answer (score 2):

Well it says on the top:

> suggested edits should be substantive improvements addressing multiple issues in the post.

I believe it's not really about the length, but about the quality change that the suggested edit brings. A typo that involved two characters swapping places (`qeustion` instead of `question`) didn't really harm the post; in fact, a lot of people would not even notice it. Replacing a word with a synonym also doesn't improve much (if it does at all), and you even admitted that you changed it to bypass the limit.

Also keep in mind that while people who are reviewing this want to improve the posts, they will not approve a lot of tiny edits simply because some may think that the editor just wants easy reputation (no offense).

Sometimes small edits are viable of course, for example if you see poor usage of code formatting, and a part of code wasn't formatted properly. In that case all you need to do is sometimes as minor as adding a single space, but the visual quality will greatly increase. I usually approve such edits immediately.